# Python / Flask / Ajax : send a dict key from client to server

Tags: python, ajax, post, flask

I'm trying to figure out which image has been clicked on my page (generated with Flask) and send the id of this image to a python program with Ajax. These images are displayed by a loop like so:

_result_remote.html:

```
{% for key, value in resultat.vars_buttons.items() %}
    <div class="tuile{{1+loop.index%23}} news col-xs-4 col-lg-2">
        <img id ="{{key}}"style="margin-top:-5px;" src="../static/img/remote/tvb.png" width="30" >{{ value }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I've tried to put this script just before the {% endfor %} statement:

```
$(function() {
    $('img#{{key}}').on("click", function (e) {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        url: "/remote",
        type: "POST",
        id: id})
    });
});
```

and finally in my app.py:

app.py:

```
@app.route('/remote', methods=['POST'])
def remote():
    commande =  request['id'];
    return print(commande)
```

another information: my page is named _result_remote.html because it's actually an include in another page that is rendered like this:

app.py:

```
@app.route('/')
def accueil():
    resultat = {'module_identique' : "", "module":"", "vars": {}}
    return render_template("accueil_modulable.html", titre="Bienvenue!",resultat=resultat)
```

accueil_modulable.html:

```
<div class="row result {{ resultat.module_identique }}" id="ajax_result">
    {% for module in modules %}
        {% if resultat.module == module %}
            {% include '_result_'+ module +'.html' %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

The include works well by the way.

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `Jinja 2.9` or above you can pass the context variable using with keyword.

```
<div class="row result {{ resultat.module_identique }}" id="ajax_result">
    {% for module in modules %}
        {% if resultat.module == module %}
            {% with resultat=resultat %}
                {% include '_result_'+ module +'.html'%}
            {% endwith %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

For Jinja versions < 2.9 you'll have to add an extension.

Comment: Hi Pranav, thank you for your quick reply, but I'm not sure to understand how I can get and send to the server the id of my img with this method, when a click event happens on this particular img?